# Spatial Analysis and Value Comparison in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm currently working with Google Earth Engine and coding some analysis. The task at hand involves working with two images. Initially, I want to select all values greater than or equal to a specific threshold in both of these images and assign them a value of 1. This creates two new images where pixels are either 1 or 0.

Subsequently, I aim to perform spatial analysis on these new images. The goal is to generate another image where the values are determined based on the combination of values in the original images:

- If both old images have 0 at the same location, the new image gets a value of 0.
- If both old images have 1 at the same location, the new image gets a value of 1.
- If both old images have 1 in one and 0 in the other, the new image gets a value of 2.
- If both old images have 0 in one and 1 in the other, the new image gets a value of 3.

I understand that this analysis is intended to compare the original images, but the results obtained from the code are not aligning as expected. It seems like there may be issues with the spatial analysis.

My code is -

```
var myRasterMask = myRaster.gte(40).clip(apBoundary);

var jbRasterMask = jbRaster.gte(20).clip(apBoundary);

var comparisonRaster = jbRasterMask
            .where(jbRasterMask.eq(0).and(myRasterMask.eq(0)), 0)
            .where(jbRasterMask.eq(1).and(myRasterMask.eq(1)), 1)
            .where(jbRasterMask.eq(1).and(myRasterMask.eq(0)), 2)
             where(jbRasterMask.eq(0).and(myRasterMask.eq(1)), 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [where](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-where) method replaces the values where the condition is true with the new value, but otherwise keeps the old values:

> For each pixel in each band of 'input', if the corresponding pixel in 'test' is nonzero, output the corresponding pixel in value, otherwise output the input pixel.

.. so you might be having issues with chaining them.

How about something like this? We start by using [and](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-and) which will handle two of your conditions (1 if both are 1, 0 if both are 0), and then we replace the 0's where we want them to be 2 or 3 (your other two conditions):

```
var imgAnd = img1.and(img2) // 1 iif both are 1. The rest is 0.
var img = imgAnd.where((img1.eq(1)).and(imgAnd.eq(0)),2) 
img = img.where((img2.eq(1)).and(img.eq(0)),3)
```

Here's a simple demonstration: https://code.earthengine.google.com/ea5c0f5f710a0af9f9cc1960bd85dc99